# deploy using Jboss Tools plugin for OpenShift generates error invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, openshift

I'm using JBoss Tools plugin in my project to deploy the application to OpenShift. When command to deploy the build failure. Follow the log of the error below:

```
Stopping jbossews cartridge
Sending SIGTERM to jboss:354331 ...
Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
Stopping PHPMyAdmin cartridge
Waiting for stop to finish
Waiting for stop to finish
Repairing links for 1 deployments
Building git ref 'master', commit 11577ee
Using Maven mirror /var/lib/openshift/56cb57232d5271befc00009a/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_95, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.95/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn --global-settings /var/lib/openshift/56cb57232d5271befc00009a/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/config/settings.rhcloud.xml clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Picos 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Picos ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Picos ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ANSI_X3.4-1968 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Picos ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 102 source files to /var/lib/openshift/56cb57232d5271befc00009a/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.770s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 23 13:43:53 EST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Picos: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/56cb57232d5271befc00009a/jbossews
```

I'm locally using java tomcat 8 and 8 to run my project. I think it has to do with it. What should I do so that I can do to deploy OpenShift?

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Java 7 and (probably) Tomcat 7 locally to develop your application so that it is compatible with OpenShift Online.  If you want to keep using Java 8, you should try deploying to the WildFly or JBoss EAP cartridges.

Comment: Thank you. It was just that.